# matplotlib unstable when running in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, dll

I'm doing a problem that obtain data from a dll to plot real time graph using matplotlib. The process run fine and able to produce real time graph. I use multi threading to obtain the data in high frequency and plot in slower rate. This is because I need a data set with 2000Hz while able to display real time.

However, the graph will stop running for a around 15 seconds while the other function that used to obtain data is running fine.

```
import sys
import ctypes as ct
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import threading

mod_name = r"G:\software\datalite\OnLineInterface.dll"
# mod_name = "kernel32"
OnLineInterfaceDll = ct.WinDLL(mod_name)
OnLineStatus = OnLineInterfaceDll.OnLineStatus
OnLineStatus.argtypes = (ct.c_long, ct.c_long, ct.POINTER(ct.c_long))
a = ct.c_long(0)
b = ct.c_long(2)
c = ct.c_long()
OnLineStatus(a, b, ct.pointer(c))

xcache = []
ycache = []

def GetData():
    i = 0
    b = ct.c_long(1)
    v = 0


    b = ct.c_long(4)

    while i < 5000000 :
        OnLineStatus(a, b, ct.pointer(c))
        cconv = ((c.value - 4000) / 1000)
        print(cconv)
        v = time.perf_counter()
        print("time:", v)

        xcache.append(v)
        ycache.append(cconv)

        i += 1

def DrawData():
    figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.title("EMG signal", fontsize=25)
    plt.xlabel("time(seconds", fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel("EMG(mV)", fontsize=18)


    def animate(i):
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(xcache, ycache)
        print(xcache)


    ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=GetData)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=DrawData)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: In my experience I have found it unadvisable to use Matplotlib for graphing and doing calculation in parallel. Somehow it requires a multitude of tricks to get right.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have alternative for plotting real time graph?

Comment: I have never needed any alternatives, because I concluded that I can just display my data after computation. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
The real time data run stable when I slice the maximum array size to 20000 for matplotlib to display each time.